# Losing raster quality when using raster calculator (ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.5

I'm currently working with DEM rasters that I hillshaded. The data I received contain nodata borders, probably the footprint of the originial mosaic dataset. As I received them separately, I can't work on the footprint to delete the nodata lines.
I'm trying to calculate the noData cells using the average value of the cells next to it, using raster calculator and this expression:

```
 Con(IsNull("DEM"), FocalStatistics("DEM", NbrRectangle(5,5, "CELL"), "MEAN"), "DEM")
```

The expression is working, but I'm losing quality of my hillshaded DEM.
Do you know how I can avoid this?

---

Before raster Calculator

[image: after raster calculator on the down DEM]

After calculator on the down DEM

[image: before raster calculator]

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 has been retired from service for years now.  10.x is *every* release of ArcGIS in the past two decades. Please provide the actual version you are using.  The commands issues before the `Con` specified a resolution for operation. We'll need the code leading up to this line as well.

Comment: I'm using the 10.5.1 version; I edited my question with this information.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand which code to give you. I'm using the tool Raster Calculator and writing the expression into the "map algebra expression" and I don't see where I can specify the resolution.

Comment: So the the pixel size will be determined by the environment rules, which probably specifies the largest pixel of inputs, for which you have a function returning pixels 5x of the original.